# How do I make a html element fit the remaining height?

Tags: html, css, layout, node-webkit

I'm currently strugging to make a node-webkit app fit the height of the current window. Below is an image of what I'm trying to achieve.

***Desired result :***

[image: How I'm wanting the app to look, layout wise.]

***HTML :***

```
<body>
<div class="header">
  THIS IS A HEADER WITH LINKS AND THINGS
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="sidebar">
    SIDE BAR WITH MORE LINKS AND THINGS
  </div>
  <div class="mainarea">
    <div class="chatbox">
        SOME SORT OF BOX WITH THINGS IN
    </div>
      
    <form>
        <input name="q" placeholder="type something here"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
    </form>
      
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

***CSS :***

```
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: red;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.chatbox {
    width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.mainarea {
    float: right;
    width: 80% !important;
    background-color: green;    
    height: 100%;
}
```

***Demo :***

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zGYa/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `float:right/left` for `.mainarea`/`.sidebar` use `display:table-cell`. Also :

```css
body, html { height: 100%; margin:0; }
.content { width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 80px); display:table; }
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zGYa/5/)

Comment: Still doesn't fit the height of the area though :/

Comment: You don't need display: table.. the key is height: 100%; for **html** and height: **calc(100% - 80px)**; for .content. I'm not sure how well calc() is supported in IE, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox too.

http://jsfiddle.net/tetm7/

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">HEADER</div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="sidebar">SIDEBAR</div>

        <div class="box">TEXT BOX</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body, .main {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.content {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}


.sidebar {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 200px;
}

.box {
    background-color: green;
    width: 300px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
}
```